# If $A$ is a Borel set and $\overline A\setminus A$ is a null set, can we embed $L^p(A)$ into $L^p(\overline A)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $p\ge1$ and $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and assume that $N:=\overline A\setminus A$ is a Leesgue null set.

> Can any function $f\in\mathcal L^p(A)$ be extended to a function $g\in\mathcal L^p(\overline A)$?

Since $N\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, $$g(x):=\left.\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{, if }x\in A\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\overline A$$ should be piecewie Borel measurable, hence Borel measurable. And since $N$ is a Lebesgue null set, $\left\|g\right\|_{L^p(\overline A)}=\left\|f\right\|_{L^p(A)}$. Am I missing something?

*Remark*: The question came to my mind as I've noticed that a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ is called *absolutely continuous* if there is a $h\in L^1((a,b))$ with $f(x)=f(a)+\int_0^xh(y)\:{\rm d}y$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and it seems akward to me why one is explicitly assuming that $h$ is defined on the open interval $(a,b)$ and not $h\in L^1([a,b])$. Is there anything I'm missing? Even uniqueness (in an "almost everywhere" sense) shouldn't be a problem, since $\{a,b\}$ is a null set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can extend any function $f$ by any nullset, and prescribe whatever values we wish in the extension (ok, keep measurablitity), it *won't effect* its integral, since integral of any function over a nullset is zero, and integrals on disjoint domains add up.

Note moreover, that the elements of $\mathcal L^p(X)$ are already equivalence classes of functions over $X$, so that two functions are equivalent iff they agree almost everywhere.
In lights of this, we will even get effectively the same element of $\mathcal L^p(A\cup M)$ whatever extension on $M$ we take if $M$ has zero measure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note that the elements of $\mathcal L^p$ are *not* equivalence classes (the elements of $L^p$ are).

Answer (score 0):

If the $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ does not mean to be the equivalent class, then the extension is definitely not unique, for you can set $g_{a}(x)=a$ for $x\in N$ and any real number $a$.

And there is no need to look only at the Borel measurable functions. While $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ consists of Lebesgue measurable functions which are $p$-th integrable.

Comment: Sure, the extension is not unique, but that is not a problem.

Comment: Wth "Lebesgue measurable" you mean the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the Lebesgue measure, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\cup\{N\subseteq\mathbb R:N\text{ is a Lebesgue null set}\})$?

Comment: Yes, that is, but usually Lebesgue measurable is what we assume about the $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ space, in most of the textbooks. Maybe probability books will say somewhat different, but at least if you look at Zygmund, Royden, Lebesgue is in issue.

Comment: I'm not used to this definition, but, anyways, could you help me understanding why you think this is relevant for the question? Seems like we would still need to argue (as in the question) that $g$ is measurable.

Comment: Of course we still need to argue the $g$ is Lebesgue measurable, just that how you argue it is Borel in such a circumstance. Since I saw that you wrote several times about Borel things, I just want to emphasize that one need no to look on Borel functions and Lebesgue class is much wider.

Comment: Okay, maybe there is one thing why Lebesgue is worth to mention. Given a Borel measurable function $f$, assume that $g=f$ a.e. (Lebesgue null), then $g$ need no to be Borel measurable, but $g$ must be Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's the reason why one is often considering completions of $\sigma$-algebras in general. But our $N$ is Borel measurable. So, this is not an issue here.